# Is there a specific difference between Abstrafung and Bestrafung?

Tags: difference

The two words Bestrafung and Abstrafung. I see that online dictionaries tell that both words mean punishment, but is there a specific difference between them?

Answer (score 3):

Both *Bestrafung* and *Abstrafung* are nouns build from corresponding verbs, **bestrafen** and **abstrafen**. There also is the base verb **strafen**. All mean the same but are used at different occassions.

**Bestrafen** is the verb used most of the time.

> Volkswagen wurde in den USA für seinen Betrug **bestraft**.

*In the U.S., Volkswagen had been punished for its fraud.*

> Dummheit wird eben **bestraft**.

*Stupidity is being punished, after all.*

---

**Strafen** is used if you are avoiding someone or something.

> Die Käufer **strafen** den Diesel mit Missachtung.

*Customers sanction Diesels with disregard.*

The past participle *gestraft* is also a stilted drop-in for the past participle *bestraft*.

> Volkswagen sieht sich dadurch bereits **bestraft/gestraft** genug.

*Volkswagen sees itself sanctioned enough by that.*

---

**Abstrafen** ist very similar to *strafen*, but it means the general public avoids something, so there's a great penalty even for those not guilty.

> Alle Autoaktien wurden für das Fehlverhalten Volkswagens **abgestraft**.

*All car stocks had been penalized for Volkswagen's misbehaviour.*

Comment: There are  more meanings (or contexts of usage) for *abstrafen*...

Comment: Please give examples.